# Call stored procedure from Entity Framework 6.1.3 code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Please consider this code - I created a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRegion
    @RegionID int,
    @RegionDesc nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Region]
    VALUES (@RegionID, @RegionDesc)
END
```

and I want to call this procedure from my repository class:

```
 using (Model1 ent = new Models.Model1())
 {
     List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
     parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("RegionID", 100));
     parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("RegionDesc", "Nima"));

     ent.Database.SqlQuery<Region>("exec InsertRegion", parameters.ToArray());
  }
```

but nothing happens. I change the last line to:

```
ent.Database.SqlQuery<Region>("exec InsertRegion @RegionID, @RegionDesc ", parameters.ToArray());
```

but again, nothing happens.

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you get any error? What happens if you try to execute the procedure directly against DB using SQL Management Studio?

Comment: it pass to end of method without any error and nothing happens. When I exec sp, a record would insert to table

Comment: You could try to debug and see the generated SQL (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20751723/2804621). Or you could run SQL profiler to see if the call to DB is made.

Comment: Instead of `SqlQuery` method which is for data retrieval, try `ExecuteSqlCommand` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use without `exec` :

```
using (Model1 ent = new Models.Model1())
{
    var regionID= new SqlParameter("@RegionID", 100);
    var regionDesc= new SqlParameter("@RegionDesc", "Nima");

    ent.Database.SqlQuery<Region>("InsertRegion @RegionID ,@RegionDesc", regionID ,regionDesc);
}
```

but in your sp not returning any recored so you can use this also :

```
using (Model1 ent = new Models.Model1())
{
    var regionID= new SqlParameter("@RegionID", 100);
    var regionDesc= new SqlParameter("@RegionDesc", "Nima");

    ent.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("InsertRegion @RegionID ,@RegionDesc", regionID ,regionDesc);
}
```

Comment: Since this call is really **not** returning any data (no result set), using `.SqlQuery<Region>` doesn't really make a lot of sense here......